# Cannot find overload with sorted function swift

Tags: xcode, swift, overloading, sorting

Am trying to sort an array of `List` objects based on their `listTitle` property in alphabetical order. Here is my `List` object:

```
class List : DBObject   {

    dynamic var listTitle : NSString!
    dynamic var listDate : NSDate!
    dynamic var ordered : NSNumber!
    dynamic var qrCode : NSString!
    dynamic var storeId : NSNumber!    
}
```

and here is my sort function:

```
func sortByName()   {

    var listArray = [List]()

    for object in cardViewArray {
        let card = object as CardView
        listArray.append(card.list)
    }

    var sortedLists = [List]()
    sortedLists = sorted(listArray) { $0.listTitle < $1.listTitle }
    reloadView()

}
```

On the `sortedLists` line I'm getting the error :

> 'Cannot find an overload for 'sorted' that accepts an argument list of
>   type '([(List)], (_, _) -> _)''.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString` doesn’t have a `<` out of the box:

```
let s1: NSString = "foo"
let s2: NSString = "bar"

s1 < s2
// error: 'NSString' is not implicitly convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?
```

This used to be less of a problem with the implicit `NSString` to `String` conversion, but 1.2 nixed that.

Various different ways to fix this, but try:

```
sorted(listArray) { ($0.listTitle as String) < ($1.listTitle as String) }
```

By the way, arrays have a `sorted` method built in (which may perform better, since it knows more about what it’s sorting):

```
let sortedLists = listArray.sorted { etc. }
```

Also, whenever you find yourself creating an empty array, then populating it with a transformation of every element of another sequence, that’s a good candidate for `map`:

```
let listArray = cardViewArray.map { 
    let card = $0 as CardView
    return card.list
}
```

Comment: The error message the OP is reporting is remarkably un-helpful. It seems like the error messages from the Swift compiler are a huge step back from the clang compiler for Objective-C. Maybe it's time for us to start logging bugs against the compiler.